# document.getElementById - trouble changing information inside a div

Tags: html, getelementbyid

I'm stuck on a beginner HTML question. I'm working with this HTML with data tables:

```
<div id="wb-tables-id-0_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
<label>
Filter items
<input class="" type="search" placeholder="" aria-controls="wb-tables-id-0">
</label>
</div>
```

This creates a text box in which a user can enter data, which filters a data table below. However, I need data entered in a box in a different area of the page to overwrite whatever data may be in this box.

I'm stuck trying to make this code work:

```
<script>
    function overwriteText(text){
    document.getElementById(wb-tables-id-0_filter).value = text;
    }
</script>
<div id="overwrite">
Write to change:<input id="slide" type="text" value=""
onchange="overwriteText(this.value);" />
</div>
```

I understand that if I could add an ID to the first set of code for the input box, it would make the process straightforward, but unfortunately I can't edit that part of the code. All the answers I've researched seemed to be variants of this.

Is there any way to change the document.getElementById line to overwrite only whatever is inside the text box created by the first set of HTML, and to replace it with whatever is entered in the box created by the second set?

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementById()` function accepts a string value, therefore you need to put quotes around the id.

```
  document.getElementById("wb-tables-id-0_filter")
```

Edit:

I didn't look at the type of element you were using. In your example the `id` is set against the `DIV` and not the `INPUT`. It is an input that has a .value property. As you state in the comment it is a `DIV` that has a `.innerHTML`.

Tip: I would also rename the id so that it does not include dashes. They don't make valid script variables.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: I had tried this before with the quotes, but for some reason it wasn't adding the text to the input box. I could use .innerHTML, but what I found was that it was replacing everything inside the div (including the label "Filter items"). But if this is the right code, then I think I must be doing something else wrong.Thank you!